# Basic dependency injection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm trying to dependency inject my repository in my Job class (using Ninject):

```
public class Job
{
    IRepository _repo;
    public Job(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        repo.SaveJob(this);
    }
}
```

My issue now is the fact that I need to instantiate the Job class from another class.
How would I create it while dependency injecting the repository?
I mean the constructor requires a repository.

Comment: Usually the objects in a repository don't have a dependency on the repository.
If you do want to create a job now, you need to use the Ninject to create one.

Comment: @Jacob
I see. But the point isn't really whether the Job is in the repository or not.
I need to "use the Ninject to create one" - what exactly do you mean here?

Comment: You could have a class that depends on Job and have Ninject create it for you. Or else you'll need a reference to the Ninject container and create it from there. In MVC as an example, your controller may depend on repositories, the model (Job) would not depend on anything. A controller could create a job and use the repository to save it.

Comment: With Unity it would be `job = container.Resolve<Job>();`, don't know how to do it with ninject... Also depending on the code that uses the class some creator function provided by DI container could be more useful.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov
The method:         System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IRepository)); gets the repository.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have implemented `IRepository` in following classes

```
public class MyFirstRepo : IRepository
{
   // Implement IRepository
}

public class MySecondRepo : IRepository
{
   // Implement IRepository
}
```

Then this is how you instantiate

```
MyFirstRepo firstRepo = new MyFirstRepo();
Job myJob1 = new Job(firstRepo);

MySecondRepo secondRepo = new MySecondRepo();
Job myJob2 = new Job(secondRepo);
```

**Update**

***How to use Ninject to instantiate***

You do need to add a reference to the Ninject.dll assembly in your project and create a separate class in your project that Ninject uses to configure the dependencies at run-time:

```
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject; 
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IRepository>().To<MyFirstRepo>();
    }
}
```

Your calling code (`Program.cs`) has to use `Ninject` to determine which concrete implementation to use:

```
using Ninject;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IRepository firstRepo = kernel.Get<IRepository>();

        Job myJob1 = new Job(firstRepo);
        // Now myJob1 is instantiated

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov
I see. But how would I instantiate a job in my example?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this is constructor injection. If I'm wrong show us how you'd do it. I didn't use Unity or Ninject here.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. My bad. But I disagree with your comment saying my answer is not part of DI.

Comment: Sample provided shows most basic approach to dependency injection. It is not practical for most usages (as one would go with existing dependency container as ninject, Unity, CastleWindor and like). Sample also does not address actual question of how to use ninject to create `Job` object and properly resolve dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ninject or an alternative to resolve the dependieces. In ninject bind IRepo to Repo and ninject will pass the concrete implementation into the constructor without having to explicitly inject your own implementation of Repo as seen in the previous answer.

Comment: Dependency injection itself is not my issue. I just don't get how I can instantiate my Job class while having the repository being dependency injected.

Comment: Your other class will also need to use dependency injection to create an instance of the job class. Please create an interface for the job class so that Ninject will take care of injecting a repo inside the job class constructor when you call on the job class

Comment: Whether I create an interface for Job or not I'm gonna need to pass an instance of IRepository to Job, won't I?

Comment: The job of the container is to resolve the dependency tree based on your registrations.

Comment: So in other words you won't need to pass an instance of irepo to jobs because ninject takes care of that